# How to make Star icon bigger when it is within double quotes

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div style="width: 1000px;height: 200px;float: left;opacity:0.9;border-color:#cc3e19;border-style:solid;margin-bottom:30px">
<div style="width: 500px;height: 100px;float:left;">
    <?php for ($i = 1;$i<=$Breview;$i++) { 
        print '<span class = "reviewSpan" >&bigstar;</span>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.reviewSpan{
    color: #FFFF00;

}
</style>
```

I need to add `<h2>` tag around `<span>` tag to make star icon bigger but it prints stars vertically , how can i avoid it and make them print horizontally

Comment: Show the CSS for `reviewSpan` please.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I added it to the above code

Comment: what's the value of $Breview ?

Comment: @Manish it's taking from the db,it's simply the rating that one particular user has given for a post.It's a Integer.(1,2,3,4  or 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code-css

```
<span style="font-size: 50px;">&bigstar;</span>
```